Service provider not loaded for one module for Laravel Module
include(/home/gtiiecom/public_html/actcollege.org.test/vendor/composer/../../modules/Cms/Providers/CmsServiceProvider.php): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory
i use laravel 10 and    "nwidart/laravel-modules": "^10",
I see this error only when I try to put the laravel application on shared hosting. all modules work normally in the local host
I tried composer dump-autoload, clear cache, and config before uploading the website online
after putting the application on the host I saw this error the command line is not available on my hosting
